# Registering user's tags in Xaramin and Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to do a POC of push notifications to a specific user in my Xamarin Forms apps.

I'm having issues with all the documentation as a lot reference GCM which is now deprecated but haven't been updated to Firebase, and specifically integrating with Azure Notification Hub.

My goal is:

1. When my app loads, it registers the device in Azure.
2. I have an Azure Function that will pass a message to the Notifcation Hub to be sent to the specific user.

From what I've gathered, I can use tags to send the message to the specific user (create a tag per device), but I can't see how to create a tag from within Xamarin for a user. I'm using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices` but it doesn't seem to deal with tags.

I've also seen [Azure Messaging component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-messaging) but hasn't been touched in a year, quite a few complaints about it not working and I'm not sure how to use the component in Visual Studio.

I've had a little look at mobile apps, but not sure if I actually need this. I'm hoping that as this is a POC I don't have to deploy and additional web api to handle this, I was just hoping to pass the device id (or installation id) to the notification hub and use this.

Any hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

THanks

Comment: why passing device id doesn't work for you? what is POC?

Comment: Sorry - Proof Of Concept. So this isn't suppose to be production ready code.

Comment: How would I pass device id? Can't see how with Azure

Comment: When you register for notification on device there is parameter string[] tags. Just put there device id

Comment: What package is that using? I'm using the `Push.Register ()` from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices` and don't have that option

Answer (score 2):

When you register for push notification in

Andoid:

```
public class PushHandlerService : GcmServiceBase 
{
.....
var tags = new List<string>() { "deviceID" }; // create tags if you want
var hubRegistration = Hub.Register(registrationId, tags.ToArray());
.....
}
```

iOS:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
......
                NSSet tags = new NSSet(new string[] { "deviiceID" }); // create tags if you want
                this.Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, registerError =>
                {
                    if (registerError != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error registering {registerError}");
                    }
                });
......
}
```

More info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm

Comment: The GCM has now been superseded by FCM, and can't seem to find a nuget package for the `Hub` class - what one is this in?

Comment: please read links I showed. It is all there including required components

Comment: Tutorials are out of date, if you try to create a new google cloud project, it gets redirected to Firebase. Have a look at the comments at the end of the articles, quite  few complaints about it being out of date

Comment: I implemented all that few days ago. Everything works. I created everything on google console without any Firebase.

Comment: I am using Azure to send notifications. It is still GCM there

Comment: Using xamarin.forms how would update new tags from a shared project? (android and ios)